# MVC Route config without fixed value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible the accomplish route config in MVC without fixed value? Does this method affects other routes too?

For example, i want to do;

```
website.com/category/my-title
website.com/other-category/another-title
website.com/another-category/and-another-title
```

When i try something like this;

```
 routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Content",
  url: "{category}/{title}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Content"}
);
```

Sometimes it works as expected but mostly it cause confusion. Some urls for default route and other static pages can not be found because mvc thinks its still category/title kinda url it is. I can fix this with some "fixed" value like

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Content",
  url: "fixed/{category}/{title}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Content"}
);
```

Is it possible to do this without fixed value and use another route's in mvc?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need attribute routing more than changing it in whole project:

Use this before your [HttpGet] method:

```
[Route("{category}/{title}")]
```

More information is provided here if I understood correctly your issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: thank you for your answer. but its still not working i suppose. when i do this mvc still try to find default route which is ' url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"'. when i try to go  website.com/some-category/test route it look for some category controller and test action. should i delete the default route?

Comment: I use this in one of my projects                                                                              [Route("~/article-{id}/{serp}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id, string serp){}

Comment: that article part is fixed value that im talking about. i guess its not possible to do without fixed values. i think i can do something like this. website.com/{category}/{title}. then i change the default value to main/{controller}/{action}/{id} something like that. i keep my custom route clean without fixed value and other routes will start with main.

Comment: This does not need a fixed value it will depend only in your parametres as you pass from the link tag  [Route("~/{category}/{title}")]  Try it

Comment: it gives me server Error in '/' Application at website.com/category/title

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this without fixed value and use another route's in mvc?

Unfortunately, if you want to have `domain.com/{category}/{title}` you'll have conflict with a lot of routes, especially the default route which accepts both string controller name and string action name.

**That fixed value is the easiest fix to the issue and it's the only real fix**, my suggestion below is somehow a work-around;

If you want to retain that route `domain.com/{category}/{title}`, you could add an if statement to your Content action method that checks if that category belongs to a Controller name.

```
public ActionResult Content(string category, string title)
{
   // initialize list of controller names, better if this from a static function
   List<string> controllerNames = new List<string>(){ "Home","Main","Product" };

   // check if category parameter matches a controller name
   var check = controllerNames.FirstOrDefault(s=>s==category);

   // if it matches a controller name, redirect
   if(check != null)
   {
      return RedirectToAction(title,category);
   }
   else
   {
      // do what Content action normally does
   }
}
```

Comment: i guess all i can do is something like this. website.com/{category}/{title}. then i change the default value to main/{controller}/{action}/{id} something like that. i keep my custom route clean without fixed value and other routes will start with main. opposite way.

Comment: @comeonalready that's a good idea too if you really want to keep `website.com/{category}/{title}`. It really boils down to you and your users, looks like they're going to use `website.com/{category}/{title}` a lot and only navigate through the site with clicking links.

Comment: i have to recreate a website without change the paths. so this is the only option come to my mind actually. thanks for your help too.